Can basic authentication present a custom title?
I use AuthName "Custom title" in .htaccess and yet the basic auth's actual title is something like Sign in, is there a way around it?
Chrome

Edge

Firefox


Did you restart apache after adding AuthName?

In the standards it  is optional for web browsers to display the “realm name” and completely left up to the implementation how to request basic authentication credentials - Please use a proper modern access control / authentication mechanism if you want to control the look and feel of the logon window

Yes for restarting. About another mechanism, please see does .htaccess offer an alternative?.
